# What is use of Cursor in Android Development?

Tags: android, android-cursor

I was going through some of code on the internet regarding the database connection, retrieval. I saw `Cursor cur1= moveToFirst()` in a lot of code and I want to know what the use of a cursor is and why we use `moveToFirst()`.

Comment: https://queception.com/question.php?question=106

Answer (score 148, accepted):

**Cursor** is the Interface which represents a 2 dimensional table of any database. When you try to retrieve some data using **SELECT** statement, then the database will first create a **CURSOR** object and return its reference to you.

The pointer of this returned reference is pointing to the **0th location** which is otherwise called as **before first location** of the **Cursor**, so when you want to retrive data from the cursor, you have to first move to the first record so we have to use **moveToFirst**

When you invokes **moveToFirst()** method on the **Cursor**, it takes the cursor pointer to the **first location**. Now you can access the data present in the **first record**

Answer (score 67):

In simple words, Cursor is a Interface whice returns collection of your query data. `moveToFirst()` is used to point the cursor position from where you want to get data from your cursor. There are methods `moveToLast()`, `moveToNext()`, `moveToPrevious()`, `moveToPosition(position)` by which you can iterate through your cursor by desired way.

For example, you have data in your Cursor

```
Lalit
Rithesh
Paresh
Chandra
```

- `moveToFirst()` - If you use `cursor.moveToFirst()` then in this case
  it will point Lalit, as it is the first data in your cursor. To get
  the next data from cursor you can use `moveToNext()`.
- `moveToLast()` - This will point Chandra as the current data in your
  cursor. To get the previous data from cursor you can use
  `moveToPrevious()`

Answer (score 29):

A Cursor represents the result of a query and basically points to one row of the query result. This way Android can buffer the query results efficiently; as it does not have to load all data into memory.

To get the number of elements of the resulting query use the `getCount()` method.

To move between individual data rows, you can use the `moveToFirst()` and `moveToNext()` methods. The `isAfterLast()` method allows to check if the end of the query result has been reached.

Cursor provides typed get*() methods, e.g. `getLong(columnIndex)`, `getString(columnIndex)` to access the column data for the current position of the result. The "columnIndex" is the number of the column you are accessing.

Cursor also provides the `getColumnIndexOrThrow(String)` method which allows to get the column index for a column name of the table.

A Cursor needs to be closed with the `close()` method call. A query returns a Cursor object.

Comment: I wonder if all the data has been fetched by the time the Cursor is created or if that may be delayed until you call methods like getCount() and moveTo*()

Answer (score 11):

Cursor is like ResultSet in java, it has rows returned by some queries with its pointer. `moveToFirst()`, `moveToNext()` and `moveToPosition(position)` sets the pointer to desired postion.

Answer (score 4):

A cursor is what any SQL query result will be stored in.

Comment: The explanation is not sufficient

Answer (score 3):

> Use the **Cursor** interface as a data collection.

It is similar to a `Cursor` in `PL/SQL` in the way that it holds one or more rows returned by some queries with its pointer.

The following methods are available in the `Cursor` interface which iterate through the `Cursor`, setting the `Cursor pointer` to the desired position:

- **moveToFirst()**
- **moveToLast()**
- **moveToNext()**
- **moveToPrevious()**
- **moveToPosition(position)**

Answer (score -1):

Cursor interface provides random read-write access to the result set returned by a database query.

Cursor implementations are not required to be synchronized so code using a Cursor from multiple threads should perform its own synchronization when using the Cursor.