# SQLitedatabase function of moveToFirst

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have inserted some values in database and queried a cursor using the insertId for data set which I got from the database.insert command but I am not getting what is the function of cursor.moveToFirst(),  Why I have to call it ? and after calling it I am able to get the inserted values in some object !!

```
 long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null,
        values);

   Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,
        allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
        null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
 Message newMessage = cursorToMessage(cursor);
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938471/use-of-cursor-in-android). Look at the first answer.

Comment: All Cursor.move*() methods are for iterating the Cursor object.

Answer (score 2):

a cursor points to your data. At first it points nowhere, so thats why you have to call `moveToFirst()`. If you would get more than one result you could call `moveToNext()` in a while loop and as long as there are results the loop goes on.

Comment: why not it is pointing to my data I am using insertId in query command, It should point it?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to iterate through all the possible values that a cursor might content each step is being explained:

```
Cursor cursor = //Reference to whatever cursor you have...
        if(cursor != null && !cursor.isAfterLast() && !cursor.isClosed()){
                //this method positions the cursor always in the first item, since there's not warranty is pointing to it...
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                //Here you have the chance to create your transfer data object and populat it with the column values...
                String column = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("columnName"));
            }
                //Here we go to the next element in cursor IF any...
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Regards!